# Child combinator and ::after pseudo-element

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, css-selectors

Well, that should be quite simple. I have the following CSS snippet:

```
.nav-item > .nav-link:not(.active)::after {
  content: "test";
  display: block;
  width: 0;
  border-bottom: solid 2px #019fb6;
  transition: width .3s;
}
```

However, I'd like to do something like that:

```
.nav-item::after > .nav-link:not(.active) {
  content: "test";
  display: block;
  width: 0;
  border-bottom: solid 2px #019fb6;
  transition: width .3s;
}
```

And finally:

```
.nav-item:hover::after > .nav-link:not(.active) {
  width: 100%;
}
```

I'm trying to create a hover effect that only works on nav-items that doesn't have the "active" class. But, that ins't working. What am I doing wrong?

Html:

```
<li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link text-left" href="#">Second Item</a></li>
<li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link text-left active" href="#">FirstItem</a></li>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a CSS parent selector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue is that, at the time of your post, CSS doesn't allow you to go *up*. It seems you're trying to detect an active class at the nested `<a>` level and apply something to the pseudo content of `<a>`'s parent element. Instead, move the `active` class to the parent (`li`) level. Then you can control the pseudo content. Note that I added `overflow: hidden` to the un-hovered state, so that the `content` was not visible. In addition, I added `opacity` to the transition to make it a little smoother looking.

```css
.nav-item:not(.active)::after {
  content: "test";
  display: block;
  width: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  border-bottom: solid 2px #019fb6;
  transition: width 0.3s, opacity 0.3s;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.nav-item:not(.active):hover::after {
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="nav-item active"> <!-- active moved here -->
    <a class="nav-link text-left" href="#">FirstItem</a></li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link text-left" href="#">Second Item (active)</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: That solved my problem. Great explanation by the way. You cleared my mind. Thanks.

Comment: @gusta Have a look at [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has)—the `:has` pseudo-class selector—which will hopefully gain support one day and render my answer obsolete.